# Initialization makes integer without a cast

Tags: objective-c, warnings

I get this warning and I am not sure how to fix it. The line where I get the warning is

```
NSInteger thescore = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"Score"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

If it makes a difference, myDictionary is a NSDictionary

**Edit:** How is this? Btw my array is a NSMutableArray and not a NSArray

```
NSInteger thescore = [[myDictionary valueForKey:@"Score"] integerValue];
```

**Edit 2:** @Bavarious mentioned that I should do the following:

```
int thescore = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"Score"] integerValue];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of call `[someArray objectAtIndex:0]` is an object. And `NSInteger` is a primitive type:

```
typedef long NSInteger;
```

(cmd + double-click on `NSInteger` in xcode to see the definition)

I guess you might actually be storing `NSNumber` objects in your array. In this case, you could do

```
NSNumber *thescore = [someArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: +1. One could also do `[[[dict objectForKey:@"score"] objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];` and assign that result to an `NSInteger`.

Comment: How is this? Btw it is a NSMutableArray in response to the answerer.

Comment: NSInteger thescore = [[myDictionary valueForKey:@"Score"] integerValue];

Comment: @user: If `[myDictionary objectForKey:@"score"]` gives you an array, then you need to also call `objectAtIndex:` to get a value out of that. If you get an `NSNumber` straight out of the dictionary, then yes, the code in your comment will work.

Comment: Thanks, that object will return an int so I think my code is good, btw I changed my code to use int's instead. Thats fine I think. Here is the new code: int thescore = [[myDictionary valueForKey:@"Score"] integerValue];

Comment: Note that `-objectForKey:` is the canonical method in `NSDictionary` for obtaining the object associated to a key.

Comment: thanks @bavarious I updated my code to: int thescore = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"Score"] integerValue];